# Solvability conditions for $a z+ b\overline{z} = c$

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, systems-of-equations

I would like to find solvability conditions for the linear algebraic equation

$$a z+ b\overline{z} = c$$

where $a, b, c \in \mathbb C$ are given. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Write every complex number as a sum of real and imaginary part, simplify and equate the real and imaginary part of LHS and RHS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $z \in \Bbb C$ is a solution of
$$ \tag{1}
   a z + b \bar z = c
$$
then
$$ 
   \bar b z + \bar a \bar z = \bar c \, ,
$$
and "elimination" of $\bar z$ gives
$$ \tag{2}
  (a \bar a - b \bar b) z = \bar a c - b \bar c \, .
$$

**Case 1:** $|a| \ne |b|$. Then it follows from $(2)$ that
$$
 z = \frac{\bar a c - b \bar c}{|a|^2 - |b|^2}
$$
and it is easily verified that this is really a solution of $(1)$. So we
have exactly one solution in this case.

**Case 2:** $|a| = |b| > 0$. Define $\lambda := \sqrt{a/b}$, it does not
matter which branch of the square root is chosen. Then $|\lambda| = 1$ and
$(1)$ becomes
$$
 \lambda^2 b z + b \bar z = c \\
 \Longleftrightarrow
 \lambda z + \bar\lambda \bar z = \frac{c}{\lambda b} \\
 \Longleftrightarrow
 2 \, \text{Re}(\lambda z) = \frac{c}{\lambda b}  \, .
$$
It follows that a solution exists if and only if
$$
 \frac{c}{\lambda b} = \frac{c}{\sqrt{ab}} \in \Bbb R \, ,
$$
and in that case all solutions are given by
$$
 z = \frac{1}{\lambda} \left( \frac{c}{2 \lambda b} + i t \right) 
 = \frac{c}{2a} + i  t \, \sqrt{\frac ba} \,, \quad t \in \Bbb R \, ,
$$
i.e. the solution set is a *line*.

**Case 3:** $a = b = 0$. That's an easy one ...

Comment: thanks for your answer. I needed especially Case 2. I have equation system . there is a proposition: provided |a|=|b|, this equation is solvable  if $a\overline{c}=\overline{b}c$.

Comment: @belinda: Yes, that is equivalent to the condition that I gave. You can see it from equation $(2)$ where the right-hand side must be zero in Case 2.

Comment: Ok. thank you very much  again.

Answer (score 1):

if we show real parts with $r$_index and imaginary parts with $i$_index or in other words $a=a_r+ja_i , b=a_r+jb_i , c=c_r+jc_i,Z=x+jy$ where $j=\sqrt{-1}$ then we have:
$$(a_r+ja_i)(x+jy)+(b_r+jb_i)(x-jy)=c_r+jc_i$$
equating real and imaginary parts gives us:
$$ \begin{matrix}
x(a_r+b_r)+ y(-a_i+b_i)& =c_r\\ 
x(a_i+b_i)+ y(a_r-b_r)& =c_i
\end{matrix} $$
or in matrix form:
$$\begin{pmatrix}a_r+b_r & -a_i+b_i\\ a_i+b_i & a_r-b_r \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}x\\ y \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}c_r\\ c_i \end{pmatrix}$$
this system is solvable if:
$$\det\begin{pmatrix}a_r+b_r & -a_i+b_i\\ a_i+b_i & a_r-b_r \end{pmatrix}\neq0 \Rightarrow  (a_r+b_r)(a_r-b_r)-(-a_i+b_i)(a_i+b_i) \neq 0$$
or in other words:
$$a_r^2-b_r^2-(-a_i^2+b_i^2) \neq 0 \Rightarrow (a_r^2+a_i^2)-(b_r^2+b_i^2) \neq0 \Rightarrow |a|^2 \neq |b|^2 \Rightarrow |a| \neq |b| $$

Comment: this is what I had in mind, but the iff part is not true. THe matrix can also have rank $1$ (and therefore $0$ determinant) but the system is still solvable (with infinite solutions of course) depending on $c_i$

Comment: that's right. i just consider unique solution case. thanks 4 feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Let $z=x+iy$ then $\bar{z}=x-iy$

$$az+b\bar{z}=c$$
$$\Rightarrow (a_1+ia_2)(x+iy)+(b_1+ib_2)(x-iy)=c_1 + ic_2$$

Equating real and imaginary parts we have
$$a_1x-a_2y+b_1x+b_2y=c_1 \Rightarrow (a_1+b_1)x+(-a_2+b_2)y=c_1$$ and $$a_2x+a_1y +b_2x-b_1y=c_2 \Rightarrow (a_2+b_2)x+(a_1-b_1)=c_2$$

For the above system to be solvable the determinant of coefficient matrix has to be non zero, i.e.,

$$(a_1+b_1)(a_1-b_1)-((-a_2+b_2)(a_2+b_2)) \neq 0$$
$$\Rightarrow {a_1}^2-{b_1}^2-{b_2}^2+{a_2}^2 \neq 0$$

This is same as $$|a| \neq |b|$$

Comment: The determinant is non-zero iff there is a *unique* solution, not if there is at least one solution. For example, with $a=b=1$,  $z + \overline z = 0$ has many solutions.